# Replace missing values with the values of related ID in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a challenge in replacing the missing values with the values of related ID as below in SQL:

I have a table as below:

[image: Table1]

I want to replace the missing values, with the values of the related ID. So the table 1 will look like this.

[image: Table 2]

Any one please help me in SQL with the above challenge.

Comment: Rather than pasting an image of sample and expected date please paste the actual data so anyone can copy and create table /insert easily.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a `JOIN`:

```
select t.*,
       coalesce(t.fld1, f2.fld1) as imputed_fld1,
       coalesce(t.fld2, f2.fld2) as imputed_fld2
from table1 left join
     table1 t2
     on t2.ticket_id = t.ticket_id2;
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you Gordon it worked perfectly fine with a little modifications as below:

select t.*,
       coalesce(t.fld1, f2.fld1) as imputed_fld1,
       coalesce(t.fld2, f2.fld2) as imputed_fld2
from table1 t left join
     table1 t2
     on t2.ticket_id = t.ticket_id2;

Answer (score 0):

Make use of CTE and update the table:

```
update table1 a set fld1 =(
with cte1 as (
select a.ticketid, a.fld1, a.fld2, b.ticketid as second_ticketid from table1 a inner join table1 b
on (a.ticketid = b.ticketid2))
select fld1 from cte1 b where a.ticketid2 = b.ticketid) WHERE FLD1 IS NULL;

update table1 a set fld2 =(
with cte1 as (
select a.ticketid, a.fld1, a.fld2, b.ticketid as second_ticketid from table1 a inner join table1 b
on (a.ticketid = b.ticketid2))
select fld2 from cte1 b where a.ticketid2 = b.ticketid) WHERE FLD2 IS NULL;
```

Comment: Thank you Mohd, the code which you given would be right but I could not execute it in DOMO dataflow it was giving the error.  Could you please suggest why is it so.  is it a Redshift version of SQL query?

Comment: Sorry Girish I have no idea about that, itsa working code from Oracle 11g and above